# Filter a Panda Series By Date Or Anonymous Function

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have an object of type: 'pandas.core.series.Series'

That looks like this:

```
1997-09-10         0.000000
1997-09-11         0.000000
1997-09-12         0.000000
                  ...      
2019-10-15    348153.430102
2019-10-16    348153.265395
2019-10-17    348153.100689
Freq: B, Length: 5767, dtype: float64
```

I'd like to filter it to results after 2005-01-01.

I've looked at https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/series/series-filter.php for the Series.filter function, but they do not given an example of how to interact with dates or anonymous functions.

Please advise.

Comment: Is the index in the Series datetime dtype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can simply do:

```
s[s.index>'2005-01-01']
```

or:

```
s.loc[lambda x: x.index>'2005-01-01']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2004-12-28', periods=10)
s = pd.Series( range(10), index=rng)  
print (s)
2004-12-28    0
2004-12-29    1
2004-12-30    2
2004-12-31    3
2005-01-01    4
2005-01-02    5
2005-01-03    6
2005-01-04    7
2005-01-05    8
2005-01-06    9
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Use [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) if want also include datetime :

```
print (s.loc['2005-01-01':])
2005-01-01    4
2005-01-02    5
2005-01-03    6
2005-01-04    7
2005-01-05    8
2005-01-06    9
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Or use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with compare by datetime:

```
#include datetime   
print (s[s.index >= '2005-01-01'])
2005-01-01    4
2005-01-02    5
2005-01-03    6
2005-01-04    7
2005-01-05    8
2005-01-06    9
Freq: D, dtype: int64

#exlude datetime
print (s[s.index > '2005-01-01'])
2005-01-02    5
2005-01-03    6
2005-01-04    7
2005-01-05    8
2005-01-06    9
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```